# Retornar valor de campo select no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Como faço para retornar o valor que está no banco de um campo select e continuar mostrando as outras opções para editar:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tipo de imóvel</label>
        <select name="tipo_id" class="form-control">
            <option selected="disabled">Selecionar</option>
          @foreach($types as $value)
            <option>{{$value->nome}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: Qual é o model, ou o código que está utilizando?

Comment: Qual model vc fala? Estou colocando dessa forma e ele retorna somente o id ao inves do nome:        
            <select name="tipo_id" class="form-control">
             <option>{{$property->tipo_id}}</option>
              @foreach($types as $value)
             <option>{{$value->nome}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>

Comment: Marcelo estou dizendo antes de enviar para `View`, o código do seu `Controller`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TrwMtWNy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que o que você procura é isso aqui:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Tipo de imóvel</label>
    <select name="tipo_id" class="form-control">
        <option disabled="disabled">Selecionar</option>
      @foreach($types as $value)
        <option {{ $property->tipo_id == $value->id ? 'selected' : '' }}  value="{{ $value->id }}">{{$value->nome}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
```

Eu estou fazendo uma checagem dentro do `option`, para que se o tipo_id do property for igual ao id do type que está no loop, ele coloca o atributo selected.

Não deu pra ver a estrutura que os seus dados estão, mas levando em consideração o seu comentário isso deve funcionar para você!

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.